# gem command referencing rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rbenv

I have some rails projects that use either rvm or rbenv. Recently I had to update rbenv to the latest ruby version, which can be achieved in the following way:

cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git pull

rbenv install 2.0.0-p353

However now I have to install bundler for the new ruby version. The problem is that gem command is going to the rvm path instead or rbenv, in other words

which gem  returns
/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem.

How can I change this to user rbenv?

Comment: probably you could delete rvm lines from your `~/.bashrc` file then restart a shell

Comment: also how does your `echo $PATH` look like?